# Deserialize JSON list of dictionaries in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, cherrypy

I'm using CherrPy and I have to make an AJAX connection to retrieve informations about a table.
The python code is :

```
    @cherrypy.expose
def projects(self):
    c = self.dbConnect()
    projects_list = list()
    projects_version_list = list()

    # Get every products
    c.execute('Select * from T_Projects')
    result = c.fetchall()
    for row in result:

        # Conversion ID to string
        id = self.b10to26(int(str(row).split(",")[0][1:]))
        if len(id)==1:
            id = "AA" + id
        elif len(id)==2:
            id = "A" + id

        # Parse db informations
        name = str(row).split("'")[1] 
        created = str(row).split(",")[2].split("'")[1]

        # Product in dict line
        dict = {"name" : name, "id" : id, "created" : created}

        # Get every product versions
        cmd = ('Select * from T_Projects_Versions where id_project="{}"').format(str(row).split(",")[0][1:])
        c.execute(cmd)
        versions = c.fetchall()
        for row_version in versions:

            # Get ID + Name
            id_version = self.b10to26(int(str(row_version).split(",")[1]))
            if len(id_version)==1:
                id_version = "A" + id_version
            name = str(row_version).split("'")[1]
            created = str(row_version).split(",")[4].split("'")[1]

            # Product version dict line
            dict_version = {"name" : name, "id" : id_version, "created" : created}

            #Put in a list
            projects_version_list.append (dict_version)
        projects_list.append({"dict" : dict, "projects_version_list" : projects_version_list})

    cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    return json.dumps(projects_list)
```

The Javascript/Jquery code is here :

```
for(var i = 0;i < data.length; ++i) //for enumerating array
                {
                     var obj = data[i];
                     for(var propName in obj) //for enumerating the properties of an object
                     {
                         var value = obj[propName];
                         $('#container').append("item : " + i + " : prop : " + propName + " : value : " + value);
                     }
                }
```

And the output is :

> item : 0 : prop : dict : value : [object Object]item : 0 : prop : projects_version_list : value : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ...

The javascript part just doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions ?

Thanks !

Servietsky

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'doesn't work'? Why doesn't it work? Any errors? Odd behaviour?

Comment: No error, nothing shows up on the page. I updated with a code that output something ^^'

Comment: Add a sample of the JSON. You might be accessing it incorrectly. @Servietsky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem some days ago, maybe it will interest someone.

Here is the js :

```
$.get( "/products", function(data) {
        for(var i = 0;i < data.length; ++i) 
        {
            $('.products_body').append("<tr class='header'><td id='name' class='product'>" + data[i]["product"]['name'] + "</td><td class='product'> " + data[i]["product"]['id'] + "</td><td class='product'>" + data[i]["product"]['created'] +  "</td></tr>");
            for(var j = 0;j < data[i]["versions"].length; ++j)
            {
                var value = data[i]["versions"][j];
                $('.products_body').append("<tr class='versions'><td class='version'>" + value['name'] + " </td><td class='version'> " + value['id'] + "</td><td class='version'>" + value['created'] + "</td></tr>");
            }
        }
    })
```

And Here is the python :

```
@cherrypy.expose
def products(self):
    c = self.dbConnect()
    products = list()

    # Get every products
    c.execute('Select * from T_products')
    result = c.fetchall()
    for row in result:
        versions = list()
        # Conversion ID to string
        id = self.b10to26(int(str(row).split(",")[0][1:]))
        if len(id)==1:
            id = "AA" + id
        elif len(id)==2:
            id = "A" + id

        # Parse db informations
        name = str(row).split("'")[1] 
        created = str(row).split(",")[2].split("'")[1]

        # Product in dict line
        product = {"name" : name, "id" : id, "created" : created}

        # Get every product versions
        cmd = ('Select * from T_products_Versions where id_product="{}"').format(str(row).split(",")[0][1:])
        c.execute(cmd)
        cmd_versions = c.fetchall()
        for row_version in cmd_versions:

            # Get ID + Name
            id_version = self.b10to26(int(str(row_version).split(",")[1]))
            if len(id_version)==1:
                id_version = "A" + id_version
            name = str(row_version).split("'")[1]
            created = str(row_version).split(",")[4].split("'")[1]

            # Product version dict line
            version = {"name" : name, "id" : id_version, "created" : created}

            #Put in a list
            versions.append (version)
        products.append({"product" : product, "versions" : versions})

    cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    return json.dumps(products)
```